# Build Python Standalone Executable for Linux using Windows Machine

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

Is it possible to create a standalone Linux executable of python code using a Windows machine? My development setup is in Windows, and I need the standalone app for my prod Unix box.

I have tried `pyinstaller` with combinations of inputs, and every time, it creates an `.exe` file.  Is there any other alternative or workaround which I can try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this with PyInstaller and just a Windows development machine.

PyInstaller creates executables for the system you're running it on. If you run it on a Windows machine, you get a Windows executable.

In the past, I solved this problem by creating a Linux development VM, and running PyInstaller there; it creates a Linux executable appropriately.

Comment: This would explain why the app I made with pyinstaller on windows didn't work on my mac.